# parameters are of unsupported type.Что делать SQLITE3

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

````
    ```case 9:
        cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'('{subpick}') VALUES (?)""", (9))
        cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'(date) VALUES(?)""", (datetime.date.today()))
        db.commit()```
````

Выдаёт ошибку в стоке             cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'('{subpick}') VALUES (?)""", (9))

Вот сама ошибка:
`cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{people_id}'('{subpick}') VALUES (?)""", (9)) sqlite3.ProgrammingError: parameters are of unsupported type`

Comment: а какой тип данных у колонки subpick ?

Comment: @splash58 subpick это не колонка а переменная несущая название этой колонки.subpick принимает лотько название колонок с типом int

Comment: хотя бы распечатайте строку запроса - как там оно подставилось.

Comment: да, и тип данных для этой колонки посмотрите в базе, все-таки